# Represent single linked list in Postgres and fetch all previous nodes for the specific node

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that represents linked lists

```
CREATE TABLE linked_list (
  node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  next_node_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO linked_list VALUES
  (1, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (3, NULL);
```

It may contain other data e.g (4, NULL), (5, 6), (6,7). But I try to figure out how to make it in the simplified form.

I try to write an sql query for PostgreSQL to fetch all previous nodes by the specified node, e.g. 3 -> [1,2]

I suppose that it might be achieved with `recursive` function. But all my attempts leads to empty results or  helps to fetch just previous node. (e.g. 2 for 3)

My last attempt looks like this and a bit weird from my perspective:

```
SELECT node_id, linked_node_ids FROM linked_list,
(WITH RECURSIVE linked_nodes AS (
  SELECT node_id, next_node_id FROM linked_list WHERE node_id = 3

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ll.node_id, ll.next_node_id FROM linked_list ll
  JOIN linked_nodes ln ON ll.next_node_id = ln.node_id
  WHERE ll.node_id != 3
)
SELECT array_remove(ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN node_id = 3 THEN NULL ELSE node_id END), NULL) AS linked_node_ids FROM linked_nodes) WHERE node_id=3;
```

Any hints how to make it more simple or performant are welcome.

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL that you've managed to write so far (as editable text)

Comment: @NickW I added the example with my last experiment

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query that uses a recursive `CTE` to traverse a linked list in reverse order from a specified node, accumulating the `IDs` of all preceding nodes into an array.

```
    WITH RECURSIVE traverse AS (
    SELECT node_id, next_node_id, ARRAY[node_id] AS path
    FROM linked_list
    WHERE node_id = 1 

    UNION ALL

     SELECT ll.node_id, ll.next_node_id, path || ll.node_id
    FROM linked_list ll
    INNER JOIN traverse t ON t.next_node_id = ll.node_id
)
SELECT array_remove(path, 3) AS previous_nodes  
FROM traverse
WHERE node_id = 3;
```

Comment: It returns `{}` for me